# Xcode 8 storyboard error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

Anyone can help me something goes wrong with me, I cant see my storyboard View, subview, imageview. All became white and its show error like on storyboard file 
"An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited."

I have open my project in xcode 8 and 8.1 beta latest xcode but both have same issue.

Main thing is that this is happening with all project not just one.
For example i am opening new project that is open in xcode 8 and i cant see that storeyboad file.  Old project is working fine which are not open in xocde 8 i can see that project and open in xcode 7.3.1. but if i open that in xcode 8 and convert to xcode 8 compatible and this issue happen.

Comment: select the view and do "update frames" . fix the other ui issues manually. i did the same

Comment: But i am not using auto layout , I have use auto resize.
so what should i do for my project

Comment: are yousaying that you can see view content but just htose blue lines?

Comment: Yes. See my screen shot i i can see all subview

Comment: Are u able to run the app and see the vcontent on device? Try restarting the xcode or refreshing the views!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with Xcode.

I resolved it by disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection):

1. Press Command-R when start hold til logo and loading status appear
2. Open terminal
3. In terminal print:  csrutil disable
4. Restart system

Comment: I have fix this by formatting my mac.
I think this is virus.

Comment: I think in my case it is force quit I'd used a lot when it think too long without any reason. But formatting .... no way!!!

Comment: Hey, what's the side effects of disabling SIP?

Comment: I haven't noticed any. More than 10 apps were released since then.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue and resolve it by only follow these steps:-

- Go to Xcode -> Preferences
- Select Locations Tab
- Click on Derived Data arrow.
  [image]
- Trash Derived Data Folder.
- Restart System
- Automatic Fixed this issue.

May this help you.

Comment: Yes, if this still occurs then go to storyboard -> Editor (in Menu) ->  Canvas -> Uncheck Bouns Rectangle.

It will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

*They inserted autolayout a few versions ago, exactly for this foreseeable reason. It's highly discouraged to use storyboards without autolayout, if you want to work with size classes, different devices with different screen resolutions, orientations, ecc.*

**My suggestion** is revert the project to previous commit, reopen it with **xcode7**, add the needed constraint and reopen with xcode8 (you will still have problems, because of the many bugs of the new storyboard but they are mostly fixable).

**Another option** to keep working with in **xcode8** it is to use a "freeform" simulated size from the Size inspector of the view controller and adapt the sizes to the old viewcontroller dimensions, but you will have to manage compatibility with all devices sizes programmatically, as i hope it is already being done. It doesn't anyway guarantee that everything works

[image: Free Form]

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
And i am using auto resize from begging, Even i have make 1 project with xcode 8 with auto resize and uploaded on apple store.

But today something happen and all project became like this.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456411/ios-project-showing-error-an-internal-error-occured-editing-functionality-may

Comment: Yes i have already tried this. 
And if make all project compatible with auto layout that is too much work for me. And after this happen i try start use autolayout  but its doest work :(

Comment: If i open that in xcode 7.3 its crash because one we open on xcode 8 we cant open in 7.3.

Comment: Aren't you using any version control system? :/

Comment: No i am not using that

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in storyboard of `xcode 8` so if you are not using autolayout then you should use `xcode 7`. now as you said in question that you are getting problem to open storyboard in older `xcode (i.e. 7.x)` that because once you open project in `xcode 8` then it's change some configuration of storyboard which are not compatible with older `xcodes`.

So now for solution Open your project in `xcode 8` -> `open storyboard` -> `File inspector` -> `Under Interface builder document` -> `select xcode 7.x instead of latest xcode 8 from Open in`

It will show popup something like `Saving for Xcode 7.x will close your document and data for Xcode 8.0 features will be removed.` Click Save and close the xcode 8 and open project in your older xcode (7.x) and you will able to open storyboard as it was before!!!

You can refer below screenshot,

[image]

Hopefully Apple will fix issue related storyboard and in newer version of xcode 8 you will able to switch project without messing up your UI! But right now there should be a workaround as i mentioned above! Try it!!

Answer (score 0):

for me I just make all the views in storyboard size to inferred

^^"