# The table view does not display the node post in firebase database

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3

This is the firebase node posts and I don't know why it is optional. I think it is the problem.

posts:

> Optional("hXCdzourFJNRLCH64GF7yZVzu0I3")
>    -Kj_auPDxdboKTgPV-9J
>    text : hello

- This the get that sets  the node in firebase database

`@IBOutlet weak var post: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var newpost: UITextView!`

```
var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var loggedinuser : AnyObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    newpost.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 20, 20, 20)
    newpost.text = "what is new?"
    newpost.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

@IBAction func didtapcancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func didbeganediting(_ textView : UITextView)  {
    if(newpost.textColor == UIColor.lightGray){
        newpost.text = ""
        newpost.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}

func didtappost(_ sender: Any) {
    if (newpost.text.characters.count>0) {
        let key = databaseref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
        let childupdates = ["/posts/\(self.loggedinuser!.uid)/\(key)/text ": newpost.text,"/time/\(self.loggedinuser!.uid)/\(key)/text":"\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"] as [String : Any]
        self.databaseref.updateChildValues(childupdates)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

This is the tableview code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ac: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var feeds: UITableView!

var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var loggedinuser : AnyObject?
var loggedinuserdata : NSDictionary?
var posts = [NSDictionary]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    self.databaseref.child("users").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        self.loggedinuserdata = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.databaseref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            self.posts.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
            self.feeds.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row : 0 ,section : 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.ac.stopAnimating()
        }) {(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  self.posts.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : viewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "opa", for:indexPath) as! viewTableViewCell
    let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - indexPath .row]["text"] as! String

    cell.configure(nil, name:self.loggedinuserdata!["name"]  as! String          
    handle: self.loggedinuserdata!["handle"]  as! String, post: post)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where is that node being set?

Comment: the node is being set in firebase   i don't  understand your question

Comment: @PeterTao this is the code  that sets the firebase node posts checked the last update in the question

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

`feeds.reloadData()`

before `self.ac.stopAnimating()`

There's no reason for you to call `self` on:

- self.loggedinuserdata
- self.databaseref (first instance)

Comment: when i remove self from loogedinuserdata an error occurs says insert self but it works for the first instance for database ref

Comment: self.feeds.reloaddata did not change anything is there an unwrapping problem anywhere causing the firebase to write optional before the node @GlennHerping

Comment: It was only meant to work on the first instance of loggedinuserdata. :) What is the output of  `print(posts[Insert index here]["text"])` before you insert the row?

Comment: the output is null self.databaseref.child("posts").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: {( snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in this line posts return 0 also i think it is due to optional data

Answer (score 0):

The issue is having an optional logged in user: `self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser`. Change it to

```
self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser
```

Comment: i changed it in the tableview and post view controllers and still i get the optional data that returns nil

Comment: The problem is with the key of the node, not the tableView code. To fix it, update the value of the node with a logged in user (see code above).

Comment: I changed it but this happened "An internal error occured. Editing functionality may be limited"

Comment: Probably just need to clear the derived data. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456411/ios-project-showing-error-an-internal-error-occurred-editing-functionality-may

Comment: i deleted and restarted the computer  and then error has gone and i am working on the old error

Comment: Great to hear! Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I changed it as you said in the first lines of the viewdidload and i still have optional data ((