# Xcode 9 Storyboard: an internal error occurred. editing functionality may be limited

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode9

When I am opening my project in Xcode 9, getting above error for Storyboard and Launchscreen.

Note: Cleaning derived data didn't help me.

Please have a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: quit Xcode and start once again.

Comment: Did many times but not working

Comment: Just click on report a bug, your query will got to apple , and after that it won't show . Check once.

Comment: Sending a bug to Apple sometimes helps, but in this case not (here). I had this issue frequently, and after some cleaning, cleaning Derived Data and restarting, building again - it worked. But this is not quite the way one like to work.

Comment: The report bug system fails.  
Just more 'It just works' from the great devs at Apple.
I suggest quitting iOS development, and switching to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by-

1. updating my Mac to MacOS High Siera
2. deleted Xcode
3. installed new Xcode from AppStore

Comment: It would be interesting to know if a new Xcode instance fixed it or the High Sierra change.

Comment: it's strange I updated High Sierra on a new macbook and copied xcode from my previous macbook and this error was occurring. So I installed it from app store and its working fine now.

Comment: I can confirm, that this doesn't help. It might help - but IMHO this is by coincidence.

Comment: For me, the error disappeared after cleaning the project and rebuilding it

Answer (score 24):

You can find the issue in Problem Report, just clink on report a bug and open the log.txt file where you can find the issue. In my case i set invalid table row height.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. The log.txt file said couldn't communicate to the simulator. I had to reboot my mac to get it to work normally again. I was switching back and forth between Xcode 10.1 and 10.2 when this happened. Restarting Xcode, deleting derived data, quitting the simulator had no effect.

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Turns out one of my buttons had a background image that IB didn't like.

Comment: I wish I'd known how to do that two days ago! I just found a detailed description there of a problem I've been trying to track down where fastlane was failing with error 65

Comment: Good! In the log I see the error “escale must be > 0” and after searching a lot, I found a png images with a “wrong” DPI. Is strange, because before update Xcode all are working...

Comment: EduTgn75 - I also am struggling with the scale error, did you just delete the offending png in your case?  I did not get this issue with the same file on Xcode 11, but on Xcode 12 it keeps crashing

Comment: Late to the party, but in my case the 'scale must be > 0' issue was caused by an image too. Opened in gimp and re-exported and problem gone.

Comment: Where are the report logs located?

Answer (score 8):

I was getting same issue in Xcode 10.2.1

I have open interface builder (Story board) as source code just like attached screen shot by right click on storyboard file

[image]

Followed below steps

1. Updated version 3.0 to 3.5 `<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0"`
2. Open storyboard as interface builder again

Its get refreshed now and I was not getting error now and view was proper also

However when I revisted the spruce code of story board the version reverted to 3.0 again.

But this worked for as refresh and resolved my problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! in my case this solves the problem. It was a hell editing on blue.

Answer (score 6):

Trash derived data by two ways either by command or Preferences.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

or

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> Derived Data
```

[image: screenshot 1]

In Xcode menu go to product clear the project.

[image: screenshot 2]

Disconnect connected device and restart Xcode and system.

[image: screenshot 3]

More: https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/266937

Answer (score 3):

This generally happens when you have a compiler error in the code that the editor can't figure out or handle. So it crashes. Unfortunately, the only way to fix this is to find out the piece of code and fix it.

I had this when Swift could not figure out the type for one of my variables.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38334815/3539959) is worth checking out as well.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case here. I've had a lots of problems like this since Xcode 9. I also repeatedly reported the bug - with the answer that it's a known bug.

Comment: @brainray What the radar number for the issue you filed?  As I mentioned in my response, there are many possible causes for this issue, and I'd need to see your logging to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia  My largest problem currently is with xib files. They randomly don't build. Then after some time (I havn't found a pattern yet), they build. Apple says: DUPLICATE OF 23140937. Any idea appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: 23140937 was documented in the release notes.  It looks like you're trying to run Xcode 8.x at the same time as Xcode 9.0+.  Please make sure you stick with one version at a time.

Answer (score 3):

After quite some tries I was able to fix it here. Xcode-select was pointing to a wrong version of Xcode (here pointing to Xcode 8.3.3).

To check, use

```
xcode-select -p
```

To change, use

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

The problem seems to occur when using a Xcode 9 instance while xcode-select points to a Xcode 8 version.
In case you need to use Xcode 8.x again, don't forget to switch back.

Comment: Weird. It set mine to blank (as far as I can tell) just randomly. I used `sudo xcode-select --reset` to fix it. It would have taken me a long time to find this.... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When it was happen to me at that time I have configuration was like,

OS : macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6
Xcode : 9.0

I have created new project and open storyboard and this error was there.

Solution : I just quit the xcode and start again and error was not that.

So, it's just requires restart of xcode!

Comment: i do forcefully Xcode closed,  it's really worked , Thanks men.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error occurred when you have open 2 different version of Xcode.
Solution: Please close both Xcode and clear drived data.now again try,  use one Xcode at a time

Answer (score 2):

Check image density. Change to 72dpi or more.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue.
 Solution is very simple just delete the derived data of xcode and restart the xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Just quit (Forcefully if needed) the Xcode and start again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Just quitting `Xcode` and open again solved this issue

```
Xcode 9.4.1
MacOS High Seirra 10.13.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today

Xcode 10.1 ; Quit Xcode & Restarting Mac Book fixed this issue for today,

Comment: Thank you, need to clean drive data and disconnect the device as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. And solved by updating Command Line Tools and/or deleting unused/older Xcode versions,

Go to Xcode **Preferences > Locations**,

1. Update Command Line Tools to **Xcode 9.0**
2. Delete derived data
3. Additionally, delete older Xcode versions
4. Restart Mac

Answer (score 0):

This error is a general error when something goes wrong with Interface Builder.  Unfortunately, the error itself does not point to a specific cause.  It is sometimes an error in the tools, sometimes an error in the OS, sometimes an error in developer code, and sometimes an error in user configuration.

Common causes include:

- Incorrect permissions / ownership set on files.
- Manually deleting files in ~/Library/Developer.
- Installing buggy 3rd party kexts (especially security or firewall software).

Answer (score 0):

> Xcode 9.3
>
> Empty Storyboard/ new project
>
> macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

For my case, this happens when I open a storyboard from a workspace.

So I got rid of workspace and cocoapods. Then just use xcode projects and [carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) for thirdparty libraries. Storyboards open faster and without this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same bug which appear on my **xcode 9.3.1** by following below step,

1. Clean the projects
2. Quit the xocde
3. Removed BUILD folder from project folder
4. Open again

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I tried most solutions provided here.

In the end, what helped me was quitting Xcode (Version 10.1) and restarting my MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I got this answer and in the log it said...

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: scale must be > 0

The reason turned out to be that I'd been converting to dark mode and making my button etc. icons using Image Assets.  It turned out that I had a tab controller and the pages it was pointing to did not have their icons set to asset catalog images yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just Quit project  and again open Story Board will ok with all the design controls. In my case .

Answer (score 0):

For all others that is facing to this problem and had no luck deleting derived data, it seems there is a bug when you try to add aspect ratio between a element and superview. So when you add aspect ratio constraint and then after you change the second element in the inspector to superview, the constraint is still in the element hierarchy but it should be moved to view hierarchy or, better, add the aspect ratio constraint dragging from element to superview and selecting equal width.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The same problem, Xcode Version 12.0 (12A7209). Apple from Xcode 9 to 12 didn't fixed no one problem with Storyboard.

Solution: Just Re-open your project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and error in my storyboard today. One of my controllers was showing nothing but a black background and blue outlines.

I fixed this as follows

1. Create a new controller
2. Copy views from the old (dysfunctional) controller to the new controller
3. Connect views to their respective outlets in the .swift file. (Constraints weren't lost when I copied the views from the old to the new controller)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using Xcode 12.2

Some time after adding a UITabBarController to my storyboard, I started getting this error. Checking the log provided by Xcode, I figured out that it was related to the tab bar controller, specifically because it's not supported as detail view for split view controller. Weird, because I didn't use split view controller.

```
=================================
    ASSERTION:
=================================

Failed to update scene 'ihF-5r-7AU, uvd-WH-zGG, Tgo-fH-4sa, ExD-dD-O6v, BUC-1K-8XU, and SVS-tP-wFU' with IBLayoutConstraint (x120), IBUIViewAutolayoutGuide (x6), UIButton (x3), UIImageView (x2), UILabel (x14), UINavigationItem (x5), UITabBarItem (x2), UITableView (x3), UITableViewCell (x2), UITableViewCellContentView (x2), UIView (x15), and UIViewController (x6).

Exception name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Exception reason: UITabBarController is unsupported as viewController for -[UISplitViewController setViewController:forColumn:] in Primary column
```

Finally, as someone pointed out, **I checked the storyboard source** code and found a few `splitViewMasterSizeMetrics` tags, one tag per tab from my tab bar controller. I deleted those tags and worked like a charm. I don't even know how that split view references were added as I've never used it on my project

So my take would be:

1. check your log
2. if you can't still figure out the problem, search on the storyboard source code for any occurrences related to the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Very old project and UI builder showing just boxes and giving the scale must be > 0 error. Had some old graphics in the UI with less than 72 dpi. Deleted those / replaced them with 72 dpi or more and voila. Instantly everything was OK. Did the usual delete derived data and reboot and and and but this was the cure.

-> Check images less than 72 dpi and repair them.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1)** Open storyboard as source code as shown below:
[image]

**Step 2)** You will see this line on top, change version="3.0" into version="3.5"

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13122.16" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
```

**3) Step 3** Restart Xcode.

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score -1):

Quit Xcode and reopen it without using Rosetta and everything will be OK.

[image: Xcode screenshot]