# Opening Storyboard fails with "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited"

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode9

Im running Xcode 9.2.  My storyboards are completely useless now.  Ive
experienced what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585044/xcode-9-storyboard-an-internal-error-occurred-editing-functionality-may-be-lim) article shows and have tried everything the
article suggested.

My issue occurred when I tried to add a single swift file to an existing
objective C project with about 320 files in it already.  I removed the
.swift file entirely from the project, then did everything in the article
link above and still nothing fixed it including removing/reloading XCode
several times trying different things.

I filed a bug with apple but haven't received any replies in a week (of course).  Apple seems to be slammed with tons of bugs lately they keep 
creating.

Now I cannot work on this project's storyboards at all and Im dead in the
water.  Really not happy with Apple lately!

Is there anything more that anyone has had success in fixing this issue?

Im completely dead in the water on this application now.

Comment: Seeing the same thing in some of our projects.  Editing very very slow

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by setting the command line tools version to the correct one.  Mine was blank in Preferences / Locations

Answer (score 0):

For my case, whenever I open a storyboard from a workspace, this happens. So I got rid of cocoapods and workspace, then just use [carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) for thirdparty libraries. Storyboards opens faster and without this error.

Note that the storyboard I am testing is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be stupidity on my part.  I had a script that was killing certain processes on my Mac over and over and it turns out that was my issue.  When I removed it everything worked as normal again.