# Xcode 11.1 Storyboard issue

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have recently updated my macOS and Xcode. I have a project which is created in Xcode 10.3 now when I open the same project in Xcode 11.1 I am not able to see the Label name button title which was set, etc..I am attaching an image. How to resolve this issue?
 [image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This link helped me to fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487099/xcode-9-simulator-error-unable-to-boot-the-simulator-launchd-failed-to-respond-m/48075384#48075384

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. In Xcode: Editor > canvas > bounds rectangles. This option show/hide the blue lines. [image: Please check attached image]

Comment: I want lable title and button title should be displayed not about the blue lines

Comment: Yes, I understand please uncheck Bound rectangles.

Comment: I tried all the option whatever they gave in canvas but none of them helped me

Comment: Please check the edited answer have you doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes i did all possible options

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your XCode?

Comment: This happened to me a few times. Usually, restarting Xcode helps. Try this though https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585044/7677455

Comment: Already I have tried all the option still I am facing the same issue

Comment: Try deleting the ViewController, and undoing it `cmd + z`, it will force refresh the view controller.

Comment: Deleted the VC, restarted Xcode, cleared derive data, still same issue