# XCode - an internal error occured

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

On My current project, I am working with both Objective C and Swift code together. My XCode shows:

> an internal error occurred. Source editor functionality limited.
>   Attempting to restore

[image]

This one happens 1-2 times in  a minute while i try to code on swift. This problem frequency became high from last 2/3 days. I have tried the following solutions [Similiar problem & solution from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456411/ios-project-showing-error-an-internal-error-occurred-editing-functionality-may?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but nothing worked for me . Waiting for solution and reason behind this foul problem

Comment: This happens to me a lot. It happens to me when I type `_ in` (underscore first) into a trailing closure. And I use trailing closures all over the place. I have to be careful to type “in” before adding the underscore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not sure there’s much that you can do, other than file a bug report and wait for Apple to fix their fragile editor.

Comment: I can't work normally for this one. I had to type every single word without any suggestion. very pathetic bug

Comment: Yeah, it’s pretty awful. I have to either wait for the editor to recover or just restart Xcode. It’s such a pain in the neck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** This things happened frequently sometimes on project that contains both Objective C & Swift code.

**Solution:** Updating `XCode` version fixed my problem, nothing of the solution mentioned in comment worked for me